# How to get blob data inside a response model with httpClient Angular

Tags: angular, blob, httpclient

I have a POST service that returns a body response of type
`{"code":0,"description":"service execution ok","data":{"headers":{"Content-Type":["application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8"]},"body":"0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOwADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAgAAAAEAAAD+////AAAAAAEAAAD////////////////...","statusCode":"OK","statusCodeValue":200.0}}`

Inside "data" there is blob-type information to generate and save an excel file with information, however, when saving the excel file on pc, the information that is displayed inside the file is the same as the response from the service (with the code, description and data)

I'm using httpClient in Angular:

```
return this.httpClient
  .post(
    `${this.apiURL}user/transaction/generate/excel/filtered/order`,
    body,
    { headers: this.headers, responseType: 'blob' }
  )
  .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandl));
```

How could I map the response of service to take only what is in "data" and generate an excel?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'generate'?
Do you want to download the Document?
You can access and download the Blob as a file like this:

```
.pipe(
   catchError(this.errorHandl),
   tap(response => {
     let file = response.data.body
     let fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
     let downloadlink = document.createElement('a');
     downloadlink.href = fileUrl;
     downloadlink.target = '_blank';
     downloadlink.download = 'export.xlsx';
     document.body.appendChild(downloadlink);
     downloadlink.click();
     document.body.removeChild(downloadlink);
   }),
 );
```